# How to log HTML input field data to the console?

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

Here's what I have so far:

```js
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.height').value);
});
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <h3>Enter your height in metres.</h3>
      <input type="number" class="height" />
      <h3>Enter your weight in kilograms.</h3>
      <input type="number" class="weight" />
      <div>
        <button class="btn class">Calculate my BMI!</button>
        <p id="bmi"></p>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

Nothing happens in the console when I enter a height and click the button. Basically, I'm aiming to build a metric BMI calculator. As a first step, I'm trying to log to the console the value that the user inputs for "height". I don't really understand why this doesn't work, and I think I'm missing something. Could someone please help?

Comment: either give your button the class check or querySelector("btn class");

Comment: add the class `check` to your `button`

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws an error on the console on the line:

```
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function() {
```

because the `querySelector('.check')` call can't find any elements with class `check` and so returns null. To fix this you could add a `check` class to your button:

```js
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.height').value);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <h3>Enter your height in metres.</h3>
      <input type="number" class="height" />
      <h3>Enter your weight in kilograms.</h3>
      <input type="number" class="weight" />
      <div>
        <button class="check btn class">Calculate my BMI!</button>
        <p id="bmi"></p>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is really weird. When I go to "Run code snippet" and expand it, the value is logged to the console. And yet, when I deleted all of my own code and copied and pasted your HTML and JS to my files, it still doesn't work. But thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That is indeed weird. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @3055.nevertrustahoe Probably just a typo in the original post, but I've just fixed the DOCTYPE declaration as well.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms] error in the console, yes. How do I fix this?

Comment: A 404 on a [favicon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Favicon) just means you don't have a favicon image at the default location where the browser looks for one. The only thing this affects is the tiny website logo in the browser tab, so this probably isn't the problem.

Comment: I think the HTML might be cursed or something, at this point. Really can't figure this one out.

Comment: Cursed HTML is the worst kind of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should be giving the same class in the button which you have used in code or it is always best to give id when we are handling events.

```
document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', function() {
   console.log(document.querySelector('.height').value);
});
//Replace you button code with below 
<button id="check" class="btn class">Calculate my BMI!</button>
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function() {
   console.log(document.querySelector('.height').value);
});
//Replace you button code with below 
<button id="check" class="btn class check">Calculate my BMI!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, neither of these solutions worked for me. I will keep trying. I really don't understand why none of these solutions, which all make a lot of sense, don't seem to work on my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Just a lil problem there mate.

```
document.querySelector('.check')
```

But, there is no element with the class `check` so the `EventListener` doesn't even get attached to the button. This will solve it.

```
<button class="btn class check">Calculate my BMI!</button>
```